# Init script is not printing any output

Tags: debian, init.d, supervisord

I am trying to run [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) init script downloaded from here: https://raw.github.com/Supervisor/initscripts/master/debian-norrgard

Reading the source, it should print out some output into stdout, but when I run it, it does not print anything and does not start `supervisord` either.

I noticed the same behaviour with `/etc/init.d/mysql`. Nginx `/etc/init.d/nginx` work's just fine.

How can I debug this?

Running Debian: `2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun May 6 04:00:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Did you read the logfile ?

Comment: @Vinz Logfile of the init.d script? Where can I find it?

Comment: No, the application's logfile. Look in /var/log.

Comment: @Vinz it's empty ... the application is not probably even invoked by the init script

Comment: try to run the script with sh -x ou bash -x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run the script with `sh -x` or `bash -x` to see what's happening.

Comment: That was helpful, thanks! It seems there is a /usr/bin/* file missing.